# Dialing USSD string in Windows Mobile C#

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, telephony, ussd

Anybody familiar with dialing a *USSD* string using `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony`?

It works when dialing a normal string but as soon as you enter the USSD ie. *"#111#"* string it bombs out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with more detailed explanation of the problem and provide some code samples. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What was the error you're getting?

Comment: It tells me cannot complete the call. The signal may be unavailable or the phone number not valid. As soon as i dial the USSD string directly into the dialpad and not via the app it works.

Comment: I don't have enough (/any) experience with this, however, "dialing" a control sequence like that from code is likely done by calling into a library and telling it to do the correct operation.  Googling for "Windows Mobile" and USSD turned up a few solutions.  I have no idea if any of them are correct (and, you need to worry about the pre-Windows-Phone version of Windows Mobile; a Windows Phone solution has a higher likelihood of being correct than does a Windows Mobile solution from before, say, 2009).

Comment: The solutions that come up are mostly using TAPI and not Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony, this has already been implemented and i'm trying to make it work. otherwise all will have to be reworked to use TAPI